# How to add a Activation Layer with a specified value in DeepLearning4J?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, deeplearning4j, activation-function

For example, the default value of alpha in Activation-ELU is 1. How to set it to 1.5(say). In other framework like PyTorch we can do this using torch.nn.ELU(1.5). I cannot find any documentation in Deeplearning4J.

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify .activation(new ActivationELU(myAlpha)) in the layer builder.